# HSQLDB - Check existing schema for reserved SQL keywords

Tags: hsqldb, rdbms

After executing `SET DATABASE SQL NAMES TRUE` the database doesn't allow me to create, for example, a column called `DAY`.

Since I executed the statement on a database catalog that I had already been working on for a while I would like to know if there's a way to check an existing schema for these violations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy of the database and edit the .script file of the copy to change the existing statement `SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE` to `TRUE`. When you open the copy, the engine will stop loading the script and report an error if it encounters a reserved name used for a database object. You can edit the disallowed names and try again until there is no error.